# Join two column with same column on while php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have table like this

**user**

```
id |  name 
1  |  john 
2  |  alicia 
3  |  alex
```

**follow_table**

```
id |  follow  | follower
1  |  john    | alex
2  |  alicia  | alex
```

**posts**

```
id |  title         | content | name
1  |  title john    | ....... | john  
2  |  title alicia  | ....... | alicia 
3  |  title alex    | ....... | alex
```

*Example* ;

```
$id = 'alex';

$select_one = select * from follow_table where follower = '$id';
    $query_one = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select_one) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
                 while ($follow = mysqli_fetch_array($query_one)) { 
                 $follow = $follow['follow']; 

$select_two = select * from posts where name = '$follow';
    $query_two = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select_two) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
                 while ($posts = mysqli_fetch_array($query_two)) {  

                 echo $posts['title'];

                  }
                 }
```

results will like this:

```
id  | title
1   | title john    
2   | title alicia
```

actual sql above is correct, but I just wanted to add a query in the $follow.

my question is, how to get **user.id 3 (alex)** into the field **$follow**?
I want something like this

```
id  | title
1   | title john    
2   | title alicia  
3   | title alex
```

thank you for that already willing to help

Comment: Is it assignment ? lol :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$select_one` by :

```
SELECT name
FROM user
JOIN follow_table ON (
       follow_table.follower = user.name 
    OR follow_table.follow = user.name
)
WHERE follower = '$id';
```

This will retrieve every user followed by alex, **and** alex himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()` as a derived field to concatenate the results of two columns.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(' ', title, name) as full_name
FROM
 //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use alias in this case also you have to implement your select query, I have tried this and works well,

```
<?php 
$select_one = select * from follow_table where id = '$id';
    $query_one = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select_one) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
                 while ($follow = mysqli_fetch_array($query_one)) { 
                 $follow = $follow['follow']; 

$select_two = select posts.name as posted_name,posts.* from posts where name = '$follow';
    $query_two = mysqli_query($mysqli, $select_two) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
                 while ($posts = mysqli_fetch_array($query_two)) {  

                 echo $posts['title'];
                 echo $posts['posted_name'];
                 }
                 }
```